# How to scrape mouseover popup web data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parsing, web-scraping

I'm trying to use JavaScript to scrape data from the GitHub home page (https://github.com/), specifically the text that appears when you hover your mouse over the pricing header:
[image]

How would I be able to scrape this text data even if someone does not hover over the pricing header?

Comment: So inspect the element and see what is happening.... probably it is a sibling or child if it is written like a normal navbar.

Answer (score 0):

It's present regardless of hover.  I.e., in this `<div>`:

```
let pricingDropdown = document.querySelector("body > div.position-relative.js-header-wrapper > header > div > div.HeaderMenu.HeaderMenu--logged-out.position-fixed.top-0.right-0.bottom-0.height-fit.position-lg-relative.d-lg-flex.flex-justify-between.flex-items-center.flex-auto > nav > ul > li:nth-child(6) > details > div");
console.log(pricingDropdown.textContent);
```

There might be a more generalized (i.e., less brittle in case the page changes slightly) way to get it, but that's the specific way to select the containing element.

Comment: Thank you for responding Marc! I am also trying to implement this program onto the website below. Specifically, I want to get the text "FREE SHIPPING. FREE RETURNS." from the popup that appears when one hovers over the cart icon. I've tried using the code you've provided but it doesn't seem to work? Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is the url:

https://www.nordstrom.com/s/ag-tellis-slim-fit-jeans-7-years-rich-earth/5606749?origin=coordinating-5606749-0-2-PDP_1-recbot-also_viewed_graph&recs_placement=PDP_1&recs_strategy=also_viewed_graph&recs_source=recbot&recs_page_type=product&recs_seed=5588057&color=7%20YEARS%20RICH%20EARTH